# Pine Script Beginner, SL and TP

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I am trying to set TP and SL but something goes wrong. I need to set my SL/TP at the highest/lowest price of 15 bars before the entry candle. If I create my variables without "varip", then as I understand, it sets a new SL/TP after each new candle. So I tried to make my profit and loss variables constant as long as the position is open, and then make them "na" again by using "varip". Also, I need to set my TP at 1.5 times the SL.
[Here you can see that the profit factor is 1.9 instead of 1.5. Also, the SL is triggered in the wrong place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/986JW.png).
Thank you in advance.

```
    //The strategy
    //@version=5
    strategy("Momentum Signal", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
    ema12 = ta.ema(close, 12)
    ema26 = ta.ema(close, 26)
    ema9 = ta.ema(close, 9)
    macdLine = ema12 - ema26
    macdSignal = ta.ema(macdLine, 9)
    crossover = ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)
    crossunder = ta.crossunder(macdLine, macdSignal)
    
    //Declaring TP/SL variables
    
    varip float longStopLoss = na
    varip float longTakeProfit = na
    varip float shortStopLoss = na
    varip float shortTakeProfit = na
    
    //Entry
    
    if crossover and macdLine < 0 and macdSignal < 0 and close > ta.ema(close, 200)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if crossunder and macdLine > 0 and macdSignal > 0 and close < ta.ema(close, 200)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    
    //Exit
    
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        longStopLoss := ta.lowest(low, 15)
        longTakeProfit := 1.5*(close-longStopLoss)+close
        strategy.exit(id="LongClose", stop = longStopLoss, profit = longTakeProfit*100)
    else
        longStopLoss := na
        longTakeProfit := na
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        shortStopLoss := ta.highest(high, 15)
        shortTakeProfit := close - (1.5*(shortStopLoss-close))
        strategy.exit(id="ShortClose", stop = shortStopLoss, profit = shortTakeProfit*100)
    else
        shortStopLoss := na
        shortTakeProfit := na
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need "set my SL/TP at the highest/lowest price of 15 bars **before the entry candle**." Then you need "to fix" SL & TP values calculated at the entry bar:

```
//The strategy
//@version=5
strategy("Momentum Signal", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
ema12 = ta.ema(close, 12)
ema26 = ta.ema(close, 26)
ema9 = ta.ema(close, 9)
macdLine = ema12 - ema26
macdSignal = ta.ema(macdLine, 9)
crossover = ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)
crossunder = ta.crossunder(macdLine, macdSignal)

//Declaring TP/SL variables

varip float longStopLoss = na
varip float longTakeProfit = na
varip float shortStopLoss = na
varip float shortTakeProfit = na

ll = ta.lowest(low, 15)
hh = ta.highest(high, 15)

//Entry

if crossover and macdLine < 0 and macdSignal < 0 and close > ta.ema(close, 200)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if strategy.position_size <= 0
        longStopLoss := ll
        longTakeProfit := 1.5*(close-longStopLoss)+close
if crossunder and macdLine > 0 and macdSignal > 0 and close < ta.ema(close, 200)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    if strategy.position_size >= 0
        shortStopLoss := hh
        shortTakeProfit := close - (1.5*(shortStopLoss-close))

//Exit

strategy.exit(id="LongClose", from_entry = "Long", stop = longStopLoss, profit = longTakeProfit*100)
strategy.exit(id="ShortClose", from_entry = "Short", stop = shortStopLoss, profit = shortTakeProfit*100)
```